# Forgot my Ethereum Address. Still have seed phrase and private key

Tags: addresses, private-key, ether-camp

I got started with Ethereum using the Get Address option on https://live.ether.camp/

So I registered and got my own address. I securely saved my seed phrase and my private key, but forgot to copy my own address.

I browsed on Google a little, and found only posts about those who had lost their wallet password and stuff.

**So, how I do I find out my address?** Once again, I have my seed phrase and private key securely with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about your address, it is not importent to remember it while you have the private key and the seed.
I recommand you to use https://www.myetherwallet.com/ (because it is easy, however you could use any ethereum client to import your account).
Under the *View Wallet Info* option provide (past) you key "whitout the 0X"

[image]